# Migrate my application for using OSB

Tags: java, oracle, soa

I need to integrate my application using OSB (Oracle Service Bus). 
My application has two major job as a gateway:

- retrieve&send message to other application using JMS
- receive&send message to .NET platform using webservice.

Any suggestions how to jumpstart migrating my application? The documentation provided by oracle is spread across several files.  I am confused as to which one has the right  technical step to me.

Regards,

Mr.K

Comment: What architecture are you migrating from?

Comment: I still use common java application and spring as a framework who maintain all thread, connection pool and JMS, so for communicating to other application not fully SOA architecture, I use web service and JMS in few threads separately.

Answer (score 0):

OSB Message Flows are the main items of interest here.  The developers guide should be your main documentation focus.

[Oracle Service Bus Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e15866/toc.htm)